# I'm getting a 'Stack overflow at line 0' error in IE 8 when I am using a simple Javascript function. How can I fix this error?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Here is the function:

```
function LoadBanner(img) {
        var d = new Date();
        var Today = d.getDate();
        var Month = d.getMonth();
        Month++; //Months are 0 based
        var src;
        if (Month === 8 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 17)) {
            src = "banner1.jpg";
        } else if (Month === 8 && (Today >= 18 && Today <= 31)) {
            src = "banner3.jpg";
        } else if (Month === 9 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 7)) {
            src = "banner2.jpg";
        } else if (Month === 9 && (Today >= 8 && Today <= 14)) {
            src = "banner5.jpg";
        } else if (Month == 9 && (Today >= 15 && Today <= 21)) {
            src = "banner4.jpg";
        } else if (Month == 9 && (Today >= 22 && Today <= 28)) {
            src = "banner6.jpg";
        } else if (Month == 9 && (Today >= 29 && Today <= 30)) {
            src = "banner7.jpg";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("bannerdiv").style.display = "none";
        }

        img.src = src;
    }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="banner" id="bannerdiv">
    <!--<img id="Logo" src="banner2.jpg" alt="KnowledgeBase" width="100%" height="100%" onload="LoadBanner(this)" />-->
    <img id="Logo" src="banner1.jpg" alt="KnowledgeBase" width="100%" height="100%"" />
</div>
```

Note: When I call the function in the `onLoad` the error is thrown in IE 8, but works fine in the current version of IE and Chrome. I read something about recursively calling a function more than 12 times may cause the error... or requesting too much memory for IE but I don't think I am doing either here.

Comment: You are changing the source of the image, forcing it to reload and triggering `onload` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the source of the image, forcing it to reload and triggering onload again.

Probably the quickest fix would be something like:

```
if (img.src != src) {
    img.src = src;
}
```

avoiding the reload if the src hasn't changed. I'm going to guess that later browsers already have this check built in, but even those are going to run your `onload` handler twice.